# Paragraph Styles

Tags: sections-paragraphs, styles

Trying to set up a section mimicking U.S.C. format:  Question - Is there a way to set up personal paragraph styles. ie. `paragraph section`; `paragraph subsection`; `clause`, etc.  `Indents` are set at `2em` each level (other than titles (not `LaTex titles`) and (not shown)..

[image]

Can one do something like: create a `paragraph style`

```
"\makeparagraphstyle{secheader}{
    \medskip 
    \leftskip{0pt}}" [  Sec. 2. Definitions ]
"\makeparagraphstyle{sectext}{
    \medskip 
    \leftskip{2em}}" [  In this Act... ]


clause etc..


\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\usepackage{makeidx}



\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\noindent
 \hrulefill
\begin{center}
\textbf{Department of Homeland Security Interoperable Communications Act}
\\(Public  Law 114-29)



This law has not been amended

 \hrulefill
\end{center}
\medskip 
\textsc{\small {AN ACT To amend the Homeland Security Act of 2002 \index{Homeland Security Act of 2002}to require the Under Secretary for Management of the Department of Homeland Security to take administrative action to achieve and maintain interoperable communications capabilities among the components of the Department of Homeland Security, and for other purposes.}}
\medskip 
\\
\textit{Be it enacted by the Senate and House of Representatives of the United States of America in Congress assembled, }  
\medskip 

\pagestyle{fancy}
\markright{Sec. 1\hfill DHS Interoperable Communications Act\hfill \thepage}


\medskip 
\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}}
\noindent
\textsc{\textbf{SECTION 1. Short Title.}}

\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}}This Act may be cited as the ``Department of Homeland Security Interoperable Communications Act'' or the ``DHS Interoperable Communications Act''. \index{DHS Interoperable Communications Act} \index{Department of Homeland Security Interoperable Communications Act} \index{Interoperable Communications Act}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\markright{Sec. 2\hfill DHS Interoperable Communications Act\hfill \thepage}


\medskip 
\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}}
\noindent
\textsc{\textbf{Sec. 2. Definitions.}}

In this Act\textemdash

\setlength{\leftskip}{2em}(1) the term ``Department'' means the Department of Homeland Security; \index{Department of Homeland Security}

\setlength{\leftskip}{2em}(2) the term ``interoperable communications'' has the meaning given that term in section 701(d) of the Homeland Security Act of 2002, as added by section 3; and

\setlength{\leftskip}{2em}(3) the term ``Under Secretary for Management'' means the Under Secretary for Management of the Department of Homeland Security. \index{Department of Homeland Security!Under Secretary of Management}

\pagestyle{headings}
\markright{Sec. 3\hfill DHS Interoperable Communications Act\hfill \thepage}


\medskip 
\setlength{\leftskip}{0pt}}
\noindent
\textsc{\textbf{Sec. 3.  Inclusion of Interoperable Communications Capabilities in Responsibilities of Under Secretary for Management.}}

\setlength{\leftskip}{2em}Section 701 of the Homeland Security Act of 2002 (6 U.S.C. 341) \index{6 U.S.C. ! 341} is amended\textemdash
\end{document}
```

Comment: You might be interested in the `enumerate` environment. This can easily be customized using the `enumitem` package.

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) the your question?

Comment: Thank you will check that out.